# Migrating a Citrix Netscaler Insight Server to AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, citrix, netscaler

Is there any proper documentation for Migrating a Citrix Netscaler Insight Server to AWS? Or any way we can do that ? Any help would be a great help. VM import is not an option as well, and it is just the "Insight Server" which i am not able migrate.

Comment: Have you tried asking in the official [Citrix NetScaler discussion forum](https://discussions.citrix.com/forum/1337-netscaler-vpx/)? And could you post a link that thread here if you do?

Comment: They said they cannot help migrating the server to AWS.

Comment: Got a link to that thread?

Comment: nope it was over the phone

Comment: Try the forums.

Comment: nothing there as well

Comment: Start a thread.